# I can't position my text to be in the left top corner?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So in the webpage that I'm making, in the "Contact" section you have a form. In the message input, the placeholder is positioned center left instead of top left (when you start writing your message it also starts at the center left position). How can I resolve this?

CodeSandbox link: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/learning-react-5vj5g?file=/src/FirstWebPage/style.css)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

instead of using an input

```
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Message*"
      name="message"
      className="input-message"
      value={user.message}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "message")}
    />
```

Use a textarea element

```
<textarea
      placeholder="Message*"
      name="message"
      className="input-message"
      value={user.message}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "message")}
    ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `height` for input you can use `padding` ,  or change `input` with `textarea` and add some `css` styles on it as well

Answer (score 0):

try it with css:

```
textarea{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  <input
          type="text"
        type="text"
          placeholder="Message*"
          name="message"
          className="input-message"
          value={user.message}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "message")}
        />
```

with

```
<textarea
          type="textarea"
          placeholder="Message*"
          name="message"
          className="input-message"
          value={user.message}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value, "message")}
        />
```